# Jasmine times out when testing rxjs ThrowError

Tags: typescript, rxjs, jasmine

**Summary: How do I test a rxjs ThrowError without Jasmine timing out?**

---

I'm testing a service that can return a completed Observable or an error. For testing purposes, we can represent it with this service:

```js
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';

export class MyService {
  foo(shouldError: boolean): Observable<any> {
    if (shouldError) {
      return throwError('');
    } else {
      return of();
    }
  }
}
```

To test this code, I have the following test:

```js
describe('MyService', () => {
    let service: MyService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
        service = TestBed.inject(MyService);
    });

    it('handles observable', (done) => {
        const shouldError = false;
        service.foo(shouldError).subscribe(
            (_) => done(),
            (_) => done.fail()
        );
    });

    it('handles error', (done) => {
        const shouldError = true;
        service.foo(shouldError).subscribe(
            (_) => done.fail(),
            (_) => done()
        );
    });
}
```

However, this code ends up causing Jasmine to time out:

```
Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I was making was that the test subscribers were using the `next()` block, which will not be triggered because I'm returning a completed observable.

The tests should be written as follows:

```js
    it('handles observable', (done) => {
        const shouldError = false;
        service.foo(shouldError).subscribe(
            (_) => done.fail('unexpected next'),
            (_) => done.fail('unexpected error'),
            () => done()
        );
    });

    it('handles error', (done) => {
        const shouldError = true;
        service.foo(shouldError).subscribe(
            (_) => done.fail('unexpected next'),
            (_) => done(),
            () => done.fail('unexpected complete')
        );
    });
```

The "handles error" test correctly utilizes the fact that a failed observable is complete.

(Also, the tests may be more readable if written using an [observer object](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing):

```js
        service.foo(shouldError).subscribe({
            next: (_) => done.fail('unexpected next'),
            error: (_) => done(),
            complete: () => done.fail('unexpected complete')
        });
```

)